# how to get canvas path with a arc

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

[image]

Now, I 've drawn an arc, shaped as follows,I did this by going through the thickness of the path and then drawing it with "acr".
I need to create some effects when the mouse is moved over this graphic by 'isPointInPath', but I simply can't get the full path of this arc

```
const path = new Path2D()
path.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, angle, endAngle, true)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check overlap by combining two checks:

1. Is the distance of the mouse to the center of the circle overlapping, and
2. Is the angle of the mouse to the center of the circle overlapping

To check 1, you determine what the inner and outer radius of the arc are. The distance from the mouse to the center of the arc should be between those values.

To check 2, you use atan2 to calculate the angle, correct it to be in the range of 0 - 2 PI, and check whether it's between your start and end angle.

Here's an example that shows those checks. Color legend:

- Red: mouse intersects arc
- Purple: angle potentially intersects
- Orange: distance potentially intersects
- Green: no intersections

```js
const cvs = document.createElement("canvas");
cvs.width = cvs.height = 200;

const ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");

const R = 30;
const D = 20;
const START = 0;
const END = 1.5 * Math.PI;
const CX = 100;
const CY = 100;

const draw = (x, y) => {
  // Prepare
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cvs.width, cvs.height);
  ctx.lineWidth = D;
  
  const dx = x - CX;
  const dy = y - CY;

  // 1) Check if the position is between START and END angle
  let angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
  if (angle < 0) angle = 2 * Math.PI + angle;
  const angleIntersect = angle >= START && angle <= END;

  // 2) Check if the position is within the line thickness
  const dist = (dx ** 2 + dy ** 2);
  const distIntersect = (
    dist >= (R - D / 2) ** 2 &&
    dist <= (R + D / 2) ** 2
  );
  
  ctx.strokeStyle = (
    angleIntersect && distIntersect ? "red" :
    angleIntersect ? "purple" :
    distIntersect ? "orange" :
    "green"
  );
  
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(CX, CY, R, START, END, false);
  ctx.stroke();
}



cvs.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
  draw(e.clientX, e.clientY);
});

cvs.addEventListener("mouseleave", e => draw(0, 0));

document.body.appendChild(cvs);
draw(0, 0);
```

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0 }
canvas { background: #efefef; }
```